# Ctrl+Alt key modifier behavior with Qt on windows when a textbox has focus

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt

I made a quick sample program to demonstrate the problem

```
import sys

from  PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class AWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget())
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(QtGui.QFormLayout())

        self.centralWidget().layout().addRow(
            QtGui.QLabel('some text'),
            QtGui.QLineEdit()
            )
        self.centralWidget().layout().addRow(
            QtGui.QLabel('some text'),
            QtGui.QCheckBox('this is checkbox')            
            )

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if int(e.modifiers()) == (Qt.ControlModifier+Qt.AltModifier):
            if e.key() == Qt.Key_K:
                #when ctrl+alt+k is pressed, a message box should open
                msg = QtGui.QMessageBox(
                    QtGui.QMessageBox.Information,
                    'w00t',
                    'You pressed ctrl+alt+k'
                    )
            msg.exec_()
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = AWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**The problem**

In this sample I'm capturing the ctrl+alt+k keyboard shortcut. The problem is that if a text entry widget has keyboard focused when those keys are pressed, it is not captured by the keyPressEevent handler, instead an upper case K is typed into the box. (this is the same with all ctrl+alt keypresses).

If another kind of widget is focused, one that does not accept text input (e.g. a checkbox, button) the key press is registered as it should and in the sample, the messagebox is shown.
Also, keyboard shortcuts that use only a Ctrl modifier work fine.

This problem only presents it self on Windows, but not on Linux, so this leads me to believe this has something to do with how windows handles the ctrl+alt modifier, or perhaps I'm not capturing the modifiers properly.

Is there any way to fix this?

**Edit**

I derived this solution from Spidey's comment.
I sublassed the QLineEdit and handled it's keyPressEvent like this.

```
#EDIT: this doesn't work, see below
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.modifiers() and Qt.ControlModifier and Qt.AltModifier:
        e.ignore()
    super(CoolLineEdit, self).keyPressEvent(e)
```

**Edit again**

Adding up the modifiers as ints and returning after e.ignore() (maybe ignore isn't needed) seems to be very important.
This is the real fix.

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if int(e.modifiers()) == (QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier+QtCore.Qt.AltModifier):
        e.ignore()
        return
    super(SaveLineEdit, self).keyPressEvent(e)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but AFAIK the events are processed from the bottom of the widget tree, so it's only natural that the QLineEdit widget captures it before the QMainWindow.

Comment: Yes. That's it.  I tried subclassing the lineedit and capturing the keyPressEvent there and I think I may have solved (see the edit in OP). Still weird that ctrl+alt is handled like shift on Windows though, now when I'm looking for I've noticed it in other Qt applications too.

Comment: glad to see you came up with it - see below, a minute before your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QLineEdit`, when it has focus, is handling the `` `QKeyEvent ``.  If you need this functionality on Windows, I would suggest:

1) Derive a class from `QLineEdit` (or whatever `QTextEdit`-derived class you want).

2) Override `virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)` and check for your specific key-combo.

3) If you find it, return without handling it, and it will fall to the next level (your window, which will catch it and print your message).

4) If you don't find it, explicitly call the base-class version of the function: `BaseClass::keyPressEvent(e);` so that normal key presses are handled correctly.

Sorry for c++ syntax, I haven't used PyQt.

Comment: Grat minds think alike :)  I'm very curious about the reasoning behind how qt handles the ctrl+alt modifier by default, maybe I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, seems strange to me too. I haven't noticed that behavior in other applications.